# Sorting an array of String based on the strings sizes (length)

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

How do I sort an an array of `String` based on the strings sizes i.e `String#length`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom String Length Comparator: what's my mistake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925532/custom-string-length-comparator-whats-my-mistake)

Comment: Java 8: `Arrays.sort(strings, Comparator.comparing(String::length));`.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938235/java-sort-an-array

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8, this can be done in one line,

```
Arrays.sort(randomString, (s1,s2) -> Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length()));
```

If you want reverse order (higher-length to lower-length),

change it to,

```
Arrays.sort(randomString, (s1,s2) -> Integer.compare(s2.length(), s1.length()));
```

**Another approach,**

use `Comparator.comparing(String::length)`,

```
Arrays.sort(yourArray, Comparator.comparing(String::length));
```

to reverse the order,

```
Arrays.sort(yourArray, Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed());
```

Comment: Maybe a one-liner, but doesn't sort in-place and needlessly copies the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that uses the length and use [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) with your Comparator. The Comparator could look like this:

```
class StringComparator implements Comparator<String>{
   public int compare(String o1, String o2){
      return Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length());
   }
}
```

Now you could sort with the following call:

```
Arrays.sort(strings, new StringComparator());
```